# An Ordered Ring does not have zerodivisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

In one of our quizzes one of the questions goes like this:

> Show that an ordered ring $R$ does not have zero divisors.

Ordering property satisfies:

i) Closure: for all $a,b\in P$ , $a+b\in P$ , $ab\in P $.

ii) Trichotomy: for each $a\in R$, exactly one of the following hold,$$a\in P , a=0 , -a\in P$$

Zero divisor states that "If $a,b$ are two nonzero elements of $R$ such that $ab=0$ then $a$ and $b$ are divisor of zero."

I tried to prove this and it goes like this:

let $a,b\in R$

then, by closure property, $ab\in P$ and by trichotomy, one and only one of the following hold:$$ab\in P , ab=0 , -(ab)\in P$$

taking $ab=0$, it implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$ , and if this is the case then it is done since $a$ or $b$ must not equal to $0$ by the definition of zero divisor. Therefore ordered ring $R$ has no 0 divisor.
But what I want to ask is that, "what if $ab\neq0$".

Comment: This is not so much a ring question as one about basic proof technique. Given $a\in R$, how would you prove using the definition that $a$ cannot be a zero divisor?

Comment: Trichotomy should be "exactly one of the following...," not "only one of the following... ."

Comment: The "Taking $ab=0$, it implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$" is very wrong; that statement is only true if $R$ has no zero divsors, which is what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ has no zero divisors iff $a,b \ne 0 \implies ab\ne 0$. Let's prove that then.

Take $a,b \in R$ with $a,b \ne 0$. Then:

- If $a,b \in P$, then $ab \in P$ and so $ab\ne 0$ because $0 \notin P$.
- If $a \in P$ and $b \notin P$, then $-b \in P$ and $-ab=a(-b) \in P$ and so $ab\ne 0$ because $0 \notin -P$.
- If $a \notin P$ and $b \in P$, then $-a \in P$ and $-ab=(-a)b \in P$ and so $ab\ne 0$ because $0 \notin -P$.
- If $a,b \notin P$, then $-a,-b \in P$ and $ab=(-a)(-b) \in P$ and so $ab\ne 0$ because $0 \notin P$.